# Lua string comparison not working as intended

Tags: lua

I just started to learn lua and decided to make a short little script for vector calculation for practise.

However, the function i wrote to generate the vector arrays isn't working as intended. After inputting the vector its supposed to ask if the entered value is correct which can be confirmed or denied using y/n. (See code below)

```
io.write("Enter vector dimensionality\n")
local dim = io.read("*n")


function make_vec()
  ::input::
  local vector ={}
  
  for i = 1,dim do
    vector[i] = io.read("*n")
  end
    
  ::question::
  
  io.write("Is ","[",table.concat(vector,"|"),"] ", "the correct vector? y/n\n")
  
  local ans = io.read()
  
  if ans == "y" then
    
    io.write("Good for you!\n")
    
    return vector
  
  elseif ans == "n" then
    
    io.write("Please re-enter Vektor \n")
    goto input
    
  else
    io.write("y/n only!\n")
    goto question
    
  end
end


io.write("Enter vector 1\n")

vec1 = make_vec()

io.write("[",table.concat(vec1,"|"),"]\n")
```

However, after entering the vector values the script immediately puts out "y/n only!" before jumping back to the marker `::question::`. After that it works as intended (See generated output below). I have no idea what i did wrong, i assume that `ans` has a value different then "y" or "n" after initialisation and somehow triggering the else-condition but im just guessing at this point.

The output this script generates is as follows:

```
Enter vector dimensionality
3
Enter vector 1
1
2
3
Is [1|2|3] the correct vector? y/n
y/n only!
Is [1|2|3] the correct vector? y/n
n
Please re-enter Vektor 
1
2
3
Is [1|2|3] the correct vector? y/n
y/n only!
Is [1|2|3] the correct vector? y/n
y
Good for you!
[1|2|3]
```

I have tried using 0 and 1 values instead of strings to confirm or deny the statement. It works as intended so i assume it has something to do with the string comparison.

Comment: Never use `io.read("*n")`, every Lua newcomer stumbles upon it.  Use `io.read("*n", "*l")` instead to eat the rest of the line after the number.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't with string comparison; that works as intended. The problem lies with *reading*: `io.read"*n"` does not read a newline - it only reads a single number. Thus if you hit <kbd>enter</kbd> after entering the vector, `local ans = io.read()` reads the remainder of the line - the empty string. You can verify this by inserting `print(("%q"):format(ans))` after it (this prints `ans` quoted).

There are multiple ways to fix this:

1. Read a single line using `io.read()`, then extract the numbers using pattern matching. Go with this if you want to be *strict*.
2. Continue using `io.read"\n"`, but discard everything after it until the newline using a call to `io.read()` right before `::question::`. Go with this if you want to be *lax*.

Comment: I now trying to use `for i = 1,dim do vector[i] = string.match(io.read(),"%d") end` to extract a digit from the input string. However, this produces a vector with a nil value at index 1, so im assuming that `io.read()` also reads the remainder of the previous line. Is there anything wrong with my number extraction?

Comment: @scrapjab yes, there are multiple problems with that approach. First of all, it expects each component to be on its own line. Is this intended? Second, it will read exactly one *digit* (`%d`) - not number! - per line. If a line does not contain a digit, the corresponding component will be `nil`. `io.read()` reads *until it encounters a newline character* (the newline character is however excluded). If you have already read a few characters of the line, f.E. using `io.read"*n"` or `io.read(42)`, then `io.read()` will read the "remainder of the line".

Comment: Okay, i think i understand why that approach was wrong. I do want it to expect each vector component in its own line. However, each component must be a number so i dont end up with a vector full of strings which means that i will somehow have to stick with `io.read("\n")`. I just tried the lax approach and it does work. I just don't exactly know how. I guess i'll have to look into io a bit more :)

Comment: @scrapjab for that you could do something like `local number repeat number = tonumber(io.read()) until number` for each component. That will read lines until the line is in a format accepted by `tonumber` (i.e. Lua number format). The lax approach works by simply discarding the remainder of the line of which you've read the numbers using `"*n"` (do not confuse with `"\n"`, the newline escape sequence).